# Infinispan Custom ConsistentHashFactory Feature Replacement

Tags: infinispan

I'm trying to configure/extend Infinispan in a way that the translation from key to node (via segment) is based on some long-term parameter configured for each Inifispan Server instance. I'm new to Infinispan and it seems to me that there is currently nothing like that. I guess that I could do that with a combination of custom implementations of KeyPartitioner and ConsistentHashFactory. However, the ConsistentHashFactory is marked as deprecated and to be removed in 14.0 (although it's still there in the current development version). So, I have the following questions:

1. Am I missing some mechanism that would enable me to achieve the initial intent? Namely, I would like for each client to have a collocated server(s) and have that as the primary node for records created at that client. And yes, I know about the KeyAffinityService, but somehow it seems to me that with some cluster changes the old entries might be rebalanced to a different node even if the original one were still running?
2. Is it still valid that the ConsistentHashFactory is deprecated without a replacement and it will be purely an internal mechanism providing the segment->node mapping, without any other possibility to customize it?
3. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible (and wanted)?

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Hot Rod client is smart enough to route the requests to the correct server where the key is stored. There is nothing you have to do in this scenario.

Comment: That's clear to me, however, it is not the scenario I need. I need to enforce a key-to-node mapping with following features:
- each client is assigned with a collocated server,
- a client is able to generate a key belonging to a segment belonging to the collocated server,
- rebalancing with this server on never moves any key from this server to a different one,
- rebalancing when the server was off and is switched on again, assigns the key back to the server.
I don't care about the actual balance of entries, let's leave this up to the request distribution between the client entities.

Comment: At the moment it is still possible. You need to implement the consistent hash and the key partitioner as you mention. The one part missing is implementing the consistent hash in the client. Forget about KeyAffinityServer since it does not work with the server (it is not designed for that). Currently, there is no pressure to remove `ConsistentHashFactory` so you are safe to use it in ISPN 14... But that can change for ISPN 15.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That brings some light into the situation. Sadly, we can't risk changing the solution in two years. And the comment to the deprecation reads "the segment allocation will no longer be customizable". Are you able to confirm that this is the general intention and that no replacement mechanism is planned? We see the scenario with the internal balancing being decided by external loadbalancers due to the records being bound to the machine at which they were created (or a collocated machine) as a pretty strong one.